# Find the missing letter in sequence

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The challenge was to find the missing letter in an array in alphabetical order.

> Find the missing letter in the passed letter range and return it.
>
> If all letters are present in the range, return undefined.

My solution was this:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var letters = str.split('');
  var codes = [];
  var missing = 0;
  var start = 0 , next = 0 , c = 0;
  for(var i= 0; i < letters.length; i++){
    var charcode = letters[i].toString();
    codes.push(charcode.charCodeAt());
  }
  for(var j = 1; j < codes.length; j++){
    start = codes[j] -1;
    if(codes.indexOf(start) === -1){
      missing += start;
    }

  }
  if(missing === 0){
    return undefined
  }else {
    return String.fromCharCode(missing);
  }
}
```

I am wondering whether I have followed some bad practices or used dry code which might cause problems in a later use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be useful if you explained in more detail what your code does. From the current description it's not very clear. A sample input and output would be helpful.

Comment: This is actually an interesting problem in terms of efficiency / possible optimization. The current asymptotic time complexity is quadratic, but it can be done in linear time. Also, judging by the `fromCharCode` at the end, you assume there is only one missing letter. If that's the case, you can just `break` out of the second `for` instead of adding `start` to `missing` and proceeding to process the rest of `codes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you don't need to split the string and then process the array. Simply you must start from the first letter and store its charcode and then process the next later and check with the incremented charcode. If there is a difference than just break.

```
function f(str) {
    if (str && 0 < str.length) {
        var desCharCode = str.charCodeAt(0);
        for (var i = 1; i < str.length; ++i) {
            ++desCharCode;
            if (str.charCodeAt(i) != desCharCode) {
                return String.fromCharCode(desCharCode);
            }
        }
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Also, `f` is a wonderful name for a function.

Comment: @kyrill: Quoting the first line of question: _The challenge was to find the missing letter in an array in **alphabetical** order_ (emphasis mine). And what's regarding letter repetitions – you are right in here. Solution to this would be really simple, though.

Comment: @Przemek I misunderstood the description. My understanding was  that the alphabetical order determines which missing letter is the "first missing letter", not that the input is sorted. And of course in that case this solution, possibly with the edit you suggested, is superior to mine.

Comment: @kyrill: Well, taken into account assumptions about input sequence that can be made, Velial's answer is indeed more efficient. But it's still good to have your answer in here, in case anyone wanted to perform such check for unsorted string. Your code's style is far better too, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

\$O(n)\$ time solution which is functionally equivalent to *@Ozan*'s original solution.

Does not require the string to be sorted, nor to contain no duplicates.

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  let codes = {};
  let min = str.charCodeAt(0),
      max = min;

  for (let i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i++) {
    const c = str.charCodeAt(i);

    codes[c] = true;

    if (c < min) {
      min = c;
    } else if (c > max) {
      max = c;
    }
  }

  for (let i = min+1; i < max; i++) {
    if (codes[i] === undefined) {
      return String.fromCharCode(i);
    }
  }
}
```